# E893 Could not find function 'spacy.MLflowLogger.v2'

Tags: spacy, mlflow, spancat

I'm training a Spacy CLI spancat model. I'm trying to log the parameters and scores using ML flow. I added the following to the config file, but I'm getting an error message. This is the Spacy version I have: spaCy version    3.6.1

```
 My code: 
[training.logger]
@loggers ="spacy.MLflowLogger.v2"
experiment_id = "training_model"
run_name = "training model"
progress_bar = true
```

Error message: RegistryError: [E893] Could not find function 'spacy.MLflowLogger.v2' in function
registry 'loggers'. If you're using a custom function, make sure the code is available. If the
function is provided by a third-party package, e.g. spacy-transformers, make sure the package is
installed in your environment.

Also, How can I Spacy the scores to log? Thank you in advance!